# matplotlib line2d set data is very slow when displayed over an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, user-interface, plot

Trying to figure this out for more than a week.
I'm creating an acoustic labeling interactive application using matplotlib, and i want to enable users to click on a line presented on top of a spectrogram and drag it left/right using `line.set_xdata()`. It basically works, but VERY slow - 2-4 updated locations per second. when a spectrogram is not displayed, it works somewhat reasonable. a random matrix is added to simulate the affect.

Python==3.8.1
Matplotlib==3.4.3

I tried:

interactive mode on/off

`canvas.draw_idle()` instead of draw

`canvas.flush_events()`

And still no luck. Anybody?
Thanks in advance!

Example to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines


class draggable_lines:
    def __init__(self, ax, kind, XorY):
        self.ax = ax
        self.c = ax.get_figure().canvas
        self.o = kind
        self.XorY = XorY

        if kind == "h":
            x = [-1, 1]
            y = [XorY, XorY]

        elif kind == "v":
            x = [XorY, XorY]
            y = [0, 800]
        self.line = lines.Line2D(x, y, color='white', picker=5)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.c.draw_idle()
        self.sid = self.c.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.clickonline)


    def clickonline(self, event):
        if event.artist == self.line:
            print("line selected ", event.artist)
            self.follower = self.c.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.followmouse)
            self.releaser = self.c.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.releaseonclick)

    def followmouse(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.line.set_ydata([event.ydata, event.ydata])
        else:
            self.line.set_xdata([event.xdata, event.xdata])
        self.c.draw_idle()

    def releaseonclick(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.XorY = self.line.get_ydata()[0]
        else:
            self.XorY = self.line.get_xdata()[0]

        print(self.XorY)

        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.releaser)
        self.c.mpl_disconnect(self.follower)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
stft = np.random.rand(1025, 1500)
ax.pcolormesh(stft, cmap='magma')
Tline = draggable_lines(ax, "v", 700)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Comment: Maybe you can you `imshow` instead of `pcolormesh`?  In this case, `pcolormesh` is creating `1537500` little rectangles. The `pcolormesh` also includes edges, which aren't useful at all with so many cells.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC! `pcolormesh` was the bottle-neck here. `pcolorfast` and `imshow` performed significantly better and took roughly the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone encounter this problem in the future - rendering with `pcolorfast` is significantly faster than with `pcolormesh`.